# How to fetch root level node in XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am trying to access element at first level in given xml. I am using below code to access it but it gives me nested one as it come first.

```
 var xml = "<grading>" +
                      "<leap>" +
                         "<controlId>1</controlId>" +
                       "</leap>" +
                     "<controlId>2</controlId>" +
                   "</grading>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//controlId").InnerText;
```

It is giving me value 1 while i am trying to access value 2 which is inside root node. Do we have any by which we can access it.

Comment: That code gives me a NullReferenceException instead (due to the use of `/`)... it would help if you'd provide code that demonstrates the actual problem. I'd second the recommendations to use LINQ to XML though.

Comment: Do you have to (want to) use XmlDocument and XPath?  It is much easier with XDocument.

Comment: I have updated code. Now it will  not give error

Comment: Right, now you've used the `//` that means "find the first descendant". If you just use `SelectSingleNode("controlId")` it will work, although I'd definitely recommend using LINQ to XML instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//grading/controlId").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath expression is

```
//controlId
```

That will find *all* descendants called `controlId`. You only want direct children of the element you're calling the method on, so you should use

```
controlId
```

So this works:

```
var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("controlId").InnerText;
```

However, I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML instead, as a cleaner XML API:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = @"
<grading>
  <leap>
    <controlId>1</controlId>
  </leap>
  <controlId>2</controlId>
</grading>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XElement control = doc.Root.Element("controlId");
        Console.WriteLine(control.Value); // 2
    }
}
```

I would avoid using XPath unless you're really trying to use its advanced functionality. To just retrieve an element, attribute etc by name, the LINQ to XML API is simpler and less error-prone (as shown by this question's existence).

Answer (score 0):

I use alot of LINQ TO XML when i am parsing XML. For example to get the root in your set.

```
string xml = "";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);   
XElement elRoot = doc.Root
```

More resources can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview

Comment: I think you mean LINQ to XML rather than LINQ to SQL.